# Pandoc convert markdown to docx, but table is not right

Tags: markdown, docx, pandoc

I have a table.md.

```
| T1   | T2   | T3   |
| ---- | ---- | ---- |
| C11  | C12  | C13  |
| C21  | C22  | C23  |
| C31  | C32  | C33  |
```

Then I want to convert md to docx.

So I use command `pandoc -f markdown -t docx table.md -o table.docx`.

However, it does not display correctly, just like this:

[image]

I don't known how to make the table display correctly, so I ask you for help.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem belongs to the MS Word version you're using.

I've test to converted this Markdown table to Word `.docx` document, and the table is well displayed.

I'm running this test on MS Word 2013, what is your version ?

Comment: I'm in China and I'm using wps office. Maybe there is something wrong is wps office.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that the problem is with the software you're using. I don't know very much WPS Office and its compatibilty with `.docx` documents.

Comment: But when I use MS Word 2016, the result is still not as I'm expected. [This is my result](http://ody3ivli2.bkt.clouddn.com/2017/09/03/TIM截图20170903094121.png)